# Read a part of massive online CSV file using its URL from command line

Tags: command-line

Is there any way that I can read a few lines of a massive online CSV file using its URL from command line before I am going to download it?

Comment: Can you give us an example of the .csv?

Comment: like in this webpage. The prescrbing data is 1GB. It is the first csv file which can be downloaded directly from the website. [link](http://www.hscic.gov.uk/searchcatalogue?productid=14944&q=title%3a%22presentation+level+data%22&sort=Relevance&size=10&page=1#top)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An slightly quicker than @musher's would be to do this:

```
wget http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV -qO -
```

The `O` will output the results to stdout in the terminal, while the `q` option supresses stuff about downloading progress etc. You would have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> fairly quickly to stop it downloading, because as it is text it will download fairly quickly.

This *might* also work - it should download to stdout the first ten lines:

```
wget http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV -qO - | head -10
```

It should be fine as long as wget stops downloading after the first `10` lines have gone through `head`... I checked and `wget` seems to stop downloading after the first 10 lines have been read. 
***Edit:*** The wget command will be closed by the signal `SIGPIPE` - see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29976/52956)

You can change the number of lines read by changing the number after `head -`

Comment: Thanks for providing a better version of the answer. It works with the "head" command.

Answer (score 8):

It may be not just the beginning of the file that you need to read:

### Use [HTTP Content-Range](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.16)

To read **other parts** than the first, you could use a HTTP request for a **range**, for example with the `--range` option of `curl`, to get a part of the file from some byte position to another:

`curl --range 500-700 ...`

Regarding the file format CSV - you would **guess which part** could be useful, get that part, and **edit it manually** to remove partial lines of data.

**For example**, to take a look at the 500 bytes/characters starting from byte 50000:

`URL="http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV"`
   `curl --range 50000-50500 "$URL"`

```
2.79,0000030,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,1108010F0AAABAB,Hypromellose_Eye Dps 0.5%               ,0000001,00000000.81,00000000.76,0000010,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,110801000BLAPA0,Blephasol_Lot                           ,0000001,00000007.53,00000006.97,0000100,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,110801000BLAQA0,Blephaclean_Eye Lid Wipe                ,0000001,00000010.68,00000009.89,0000040,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,1201010F0BBAAAA,Locorten-Viof$
```

Note how the first and last line are **cut off**, as the actual part of the file was "just some text" of the file, not "some CSV records".

### When Range is not supported

Common web servers support "Range" in general,
but it's possible that for some reason **"Range" is not working**
(eg. it's not supported by a custom server, or it does not work because there is a **proxy** in between)

In this case, we **can not avoid** to download the **data before the part** we're interested in. But then, we can cut out the part we need, by bytes, or by lines:

`URL="http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV"`
   `curl -s "$URL" | head -c 50500 | tail -c 500`

```
2.79,0000030,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,1108010F0AAABAB,Hypromellose_Eye Dps 0.5%               ,0000001,00000000.81,00000000.76,0000010,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,110801000BLAPA0,Blephasol_Lot                           ,0000001,00000007.53,00000006.97,0000100,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,110801000BLAQA0,Blephaclean_Eye Lid Wipe                ,0000001,00000010.68,00000009.89,0000040,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,1201010F0BBAAAA,Locorten-Viof$
```

Just the same!

### Read by line

To get lines, instead of characters, use `-n` instead of `-c`.
For lines 100 to 110 ("the last 10 lines of the lines up to 110"):

`URL="http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV"`
   `curl -s "$URL" | head -n 110 | tail -n 10`

```
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0206030Y0AAAAAA,Ivabradine_Tab 5mg                      ,0000001,00000020.09,00000018.68,0000028,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0208010W0AAAIAI,Tinzaparin Sod_Inj 20 000u/ml 0.7ml Pfs ,0000003,00000154.77,00000143.20,0000013,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0208010W0AAANAN,Tinzaparin Sod_Inj 10 000u/ml 2ml Vl    ,0000001,00000021.13,00000019.65,0000002,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0208020V0AAAAAA,Warfarin Sod_Tab 1mg                    ,0000002,00000001.34,00000001.37,0000042,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0209000A0AAAJAJ,Aspirin_Tab 75mg                        ,0000001,00000000.12,00000000.22,0000004,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0211000P0AAACAC,Tranexamic Acid_Tab 500mg               ,0000001,00000006.31,00000005.85,0000060,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0212000Y0AAADAD,Simvastatin_Tab 40mg                    ,0000001,00000000.17,00000000.27,0000004,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0301011R0AAAPAP,Salbutamol_Inha 100mcg (200 D) CFF      ,0000037,00000058.50,00000054.54,0000039,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0301011R0BEAIAP,Ventolin_Evohaler 100mcg (200 D)        ,0000014,00000021.00,00000019.59,0000014,201403,                  
Q44,RXA,Y00327,0301011V0BBAMAL,Bricanyl_Turbohaler 500mcg (100 D)      ,0000001,00000006.92,00000006.41,0000001,201403,
```

Now, as CSV records are lines, we have a clean start and end of the section.

The HTTP Content-Range does not support using line ranges; The HTTP server would need to read the whole file, including the part before the range, to count line numbers.

Comment: +1 cause scripts aren't supossed to be interactive and other answers need user to hit ctrl-c.

Comment: Note: Not all servers allow partial downloads. In that case, curl -r or specifying a partial download will not work. Piping to head, with both burl and wget, works.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT for anyone reading this after: My answer works, but keep going, the answers below are better.

So if you right click the actual links for the data sets you can choose `Copy link address` (in chrome, I assume similar options in Firefox/others)

The easiest advice I can give to look at the top few line is this:

Open a terminal, and make a directory for your files (I'll put it on the Desktop and call it Files)

```
mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Files
```

Now, go into that directory..

```
cd ~/Desktop/Files
```

now, using the link that you copied from above (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste it into terminal) type

```
wget http://datagov.ic.nhs.uk/presentation/2014_03_March/T201403PDPI+BNFT.CSV
```

(that's the first link on the page, for your reference).

Now, to check that it's what you want just hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to stop the file transfer (wget looks for the file at that location, the URL, and downloads it. This stops the transfer). Once it's stopped use your favorite text editor to open it via

```
gedit T2014 ...
```

or you can read it on the command line with

```
cat T2014 ...
```

If it is what you want, just re-run the wget command and let it finish. If not, you can safely remove the T2014 ... file.

Comment: Thanks you very much for a very quick response. And it works very well.